# How do interact with a price-slider with 2 handle in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

now i can  interact  with price-slider but price filtration not impacted as attached 
- price-slider handle low
- price-slider handle high ,
site : https://www.tajawal.ae/en/flights/DXB-RUH/2019-03-30/Economy/1Adult
HTML

```
<div class="horizontal-slider" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="bar bar-0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 176.001px;"></div>
    <div class="bar bar-1" style="position: absolute; left: 48.999px; right: 54.975px;"></div>
    <div class="bar bar-2" style="position: absolute; left: 170.025px; right: 0px;"></div>
    <div class="handle handle-0 active" tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-valuenow="1226.36" aria-valuemin="94.36"
         aria-valuemax="5292.42" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 48.999px; will-change: left;"></div>
    <div class="handle handle-1 " tabindex="0" role="slider" aria-valuenow="4022.36" aria-valuemin="94.36"
         aria-valuemax="5292.42" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 170.025px; will-change: left;"></div>
</div>
```

cypress step

```
 cy.get('#content-section div.horizontal-slider')
            .find('div.handle.handle-1').invoke('attr', 'style', "position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 150.025px; will-change: left;").trigger('change')
        cy.get('#content-section div.horizontal-slider')
            .find('div.handle.handle-0').invoke('attr', 'style', "position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 56.025px; will-change: left;").click()
```

[image]

Comment: If you came up with a different/better solution please, let us know, otherwise accept my answer. Both could be useful for other users looking for the same answer 

Answer (score 1):

It isn't related to Cypress. Basically, you're missing how a slider updates when you're interacting with it:

- (in the Javascript code of the page, not in Cypress) the script that needs to manage the slider registers some event listeners (such as `mousedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup` or `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` etc.)
- when the user interacts (**step 0**) with the handle the event callbacks are invoked and they

  - **1** - calculate a percentage value that indicates how much the handle has been dragged
  - **2** - update the `left` property of the handle element itself
  - **3** - update the bar background
  - **4** - finally, they invoke the callback that the developer passed (to update the rest of the UI accordingly to the handle drag)

What you're doing with Cypress is basically changing the **result** of the handle drag. You're changing the result of step 4 but the result only... You, instead, need to hack step 1 or act as the user and replicate step 0 (that's what you're trying to accomplish in your example).

So: I can you accomplish it with Cypress? You need to trigger the events listened by the script of the app (`mousedown`, `mousemove` etc.). Take a look

- at the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/trigger.html#Usage)
- at [an example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/issues/173)
- an [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/845) about that with some more examples

Let me know if you need something more